# git pull --rebase vs --no-rebase when there are unstaged changes

Tags: git

Why does git pull --rebase fail when I have unstaged changes, unlike the default git pull (git fetch + git merge) which succeeds even if there are unstaged changes. I expect the default git pull behaviour even when I use --rebase option since I did not make any local commits yet. Can someone explain why is this not the case.

Answer (score 1):

that is because you cannot rebase when you have unstaged changes. 
try to run git rebase when  you have unstaged changes and it will print an error.

came across this : http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/why-is-merging-with-unstaged-changes-allowed-when-rebasing-is-not-td6089097.html

quoting from the above link:

> git-merge manpage: "Warning: Running git merge with uncommitted
>   changes  is discouraged: while possible, it leaves you in a state that
>   is hard to  back out of in the case of a conflict."
>
> I would imagine that if its a bad idea for git-merge, its a really bad
>   idea for git-rebase...